# How can I forward sound output of some Ubuntu virtual machine to my Windows computer?

Tags: windows, linux, networking, audio

Is there a way to forward sound output from some virtual machine running Ubuntu to my Windows laptop for example using some sound server (pulse) on Ubuntu and connect to it in Windows?

Comment: Do you know how I can send PulseAudio output to a Windows client over the network? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might not be helpful, and I've tried looking for the same style of question asked previous in other areas, the answer which I've read about working previous was installing the drivers for the machines sound onto the linux box, it may not be of much help though.

Comment: What do you mean with "drivers for the machines sound"? The Linux machine does not have any sound card.

Comment: I mean the onboard sound on your laptop, see if you can find the corresponding sound drivers for linux.

Comment: [Where 1 person has had the problem](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1754620#1754620)

Comment: I do not want to output sound to the VM host. The VM host is a rack server without sound hardware. I want to transfer it over the network possibly using some audio streaming software.